# Why isn't ssh-agent authenticating the private key's passphrase when I use Ansible?

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-agent, passphrase

**In short**,

ssh-agent will authenticate the passphrase when I ssh into the remote server from the command line, but whenever I execute an ansible playbook it asks for the passphrase. My question is, **why won't ssh-agent authenticate the passphrase for Ansible? How can I get it to work?**

**In detail**,

I created a password protected private key and corresponding public key and uploaded the public key to the server. 
I invoked the ssh-agent using `eval $(ssh-agent)` and then `ssh-add /etc/ansible/ssh/private-key.pem`

Typing `ssh-agent -l` shows that the key has been added.

I can successfully ssh into the machine from the command line using `ssh username@ipaddress` without being asked for the passphrase.
but if I execute a playbook or do something like `sudo ansible -m ping server` it will say

> Enter passphrase for key '/etc/ansible/ssh/private-key.pem':

I tried it again in verbose mode and it gives me the following information

> ansible 2.4.2.0
>   config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg   configured
>   module search path = [u'/etc/ansible/library']
>   ansible python module
>   location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
>   executable
>   location = /usr/bin/ansible
>   python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20
>   2017, 18:23:56) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as
>   config file Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
>
> META: ran handlers Using module file
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/system/ping.py
>   <35.230.127.195> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: user6
>   <35.230.127.195> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o
>   ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22 -o
>   'IdentityFile="/etc/ansible/ssh/private-key.pem"' -o
>   KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o
>   PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
>   -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=user6 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/user6/.ansible/cp/e26536be01 35.230.127.195 '/bin/sh
>   -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"'' Enter passphrase for key '/etc/ansible/ssh/private-key.pem':

**My Environment**

- Ansible version is 2.4.2.0
- Python version is  2.7.12
- OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g
- The ssh keys were created using RSA (not SSH-1 RSA)
  and 4096 bits.
- In ansible.cfg transport is set to smart.
- The key is encrypted using ansible-vault, but I've tried doing it
  without encryption and it makes no difference.

Please help, I don't have much hair left.

**UPDATE:** Using `transport = local` executes everything locally (ie it doesn't execute the ansible playbook on the remote server(even though it looks like it does)).

Answer (score -1):

Go to ansible.cfg file at below location:

> /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

And set the transport = local :

```
transport = local
```

Thanks